# Thread affinity to session or user

Tags: spring-boot

Our database is a graph database configured to use snapshot isolation. Snapshot isolation isn’t quite strong enough to stop edge cases from occurring when a user does multiple actions quickly in succession.

Having the same thread handle the users other request, essentially user afffinity to a thread, would solve this problem for us. Another way of putting it is sticky sessions, for users to stick to threads.

Is this possible with spring-boot?